# CUDA in a CLR Project

Tags: cuda, clr

I am trying to transfer a pattern recognition (PR) algorithm used in a Visual Studio 2010 Forms project (CLR) to CUDA.

The CUDA part called from a console project works fine as well as the CLR project itself.

When I am replacing the PR algorithm with the CUDA alternative I am getting a Linker error:

"AssemblyInfo.obj : fatal error LNK1313: pure module detected; cannot link with ijw/native modules".

Has anybody tried to mix CLR code with CUDA successfully?
Are there any ideas or any suggestions?

Comment: Just change the /clr option from the General page in the project properties.  You don't want /clr:pure.  Nothing pure about it.  Select /clr

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have two pieces of code, one is a CLR console application and the other is a native library. First you will have to use a dll (not sure if you were using a static library). Second you can connect to it in two ways:

1. You can use [P/Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446536.aspx). This will make the CLR code access the native dll.
2. You can change your native library to be a mixed library and expose a ref class that wraps your native code. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++/CLI) for more details.